# sending command to salt from fail2ban

Tags: fail2ban, saltstack

what I'm trying to do is modify my action.d/iptables-allports.conf:

```
actionban = ssh fail2ban@saltmaster.net 'salt '*' iptables.insert position=1 rule='-s <ip> -j DROP -m comment --comment "<server> | <name> | hits: <failures> | time: <time>"'
```

On my fail2ban actionban, I want it to ssh to the saltmaster and issue the above command so that it sends the iptables drop to every minion.

The command works perfectly fine without salt, when I just ssh to a single server.

The problem here is I don't know how to nest the single quote ' correctly when I add **salt '*'** without breaking the command above.

Can someone advise how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
actionban = ssh fail2ban@saltmaster.net 'salt \'*\' iptables.insert position=1 rule=\'-s <ip> -j DROP -m comment --comment "<server> | <name> | hits: <failures> | time: <time>"'
```

You can always add a `\'` to escape inner quotes.